# How can i write the value from DateTime.Now into Excel

Tags: c#, datetime, excel-2010, return-value, xlsx

I am working on a school project and im using microsoft visual studio 2010 language c# (I have teached only C and a little bit of C++). I am making an Excel file. I'm using something like "add reference", .COM and add library from excel.

I can make a page some text in row and col now.

When I push `button1_Click`, it opens my Excel file, and shows me the string `"date"` on location [1,2].  For my `button2_click` he is showing me my `DateTime.Now` (MessageBox...)

Short code version:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public string ReturnValue1 { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
        {      
            ....stuff      
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Date";     
            ....      
            //now i want is oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = .//that shows me the actual date
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime theDate;       //variabele theDate
            theDate = DateTime.Now;  //  Date + time
            MessageBox.Show(theDate.ToString("   dd-MM-yyyy")); //only date
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to deal with it (to send my DATE to print it in Excel) if it is possible?

Comment: The answer is you your first button1 click event. In your button1 click you have oSheet.Cells[1,2] = "Date".  So same concept oSheet.Cells[2,2] = DateTime.Now.ToString("   dd-MM-yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there. Only thing missing is to set the cell value. Try this

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = DateTime.Now.ToString("   dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

This will set the date as a string. You can also set the data as a date so that Excel can deal with the value directly:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = DateTime.Today; // date only, no time
}
```

Play a little bit around and you'll find how easy it is to set cell and range values.